Synchronizing point layer with external table in QGIS
In QGIS I have an external table imported from MySQL where several users insert data through a website. This table is imported into QGIS and I have a join with a geopack that contains the x and through the cadastral reference.
After, I created a layer from this imported table with the same data to be able to add points to the areas of the map.
When users from the web update the table, the one imported into QGIS is updated, but the new table created from the points is not and therefore I must always update it manually.
So in that point layer, I have gone to the "Dependencies" tab and I have marked that it is updated when the imported table is.
But it doesn't work. The problem is that even if I do that if I insert or update the imported table, the points in the new table are not updated automatically.
What can I do?

As you created an independent layer it wont update, you may create a virtual layer that will stay in sync or try to write a script to update or recreate your layer each time the data are updated...
